# Average search result count in Internal search Piwik Pro

Tags: javascript, matomo

I need to setup Average search result count in Internal search for a website.

I created a URL variable called `search_term` to catch the search term and custom JS variable called `resultCount` to catch the search result count,

Custom JS variable as follows:

```
function getTotalResults() {
  var totalResultsElement = document.querySelector('.total-results');
  var totalResultsValue = parseInt(totalResultsElement.textContent);

  if (isNaN(totalResultsValue)) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    console.log(totalResultsValue); // Output: 2090
    return totalResultsValue;
  }
}`
```

But the value of this `resultCount` variable does not reflect within following function I created as a tag.

`_paq.push([‘trackSiteSearch’,{{ search_term }},‘’,{{ resultCount}});`

I’m using page view trigger for this tag.
what is the reason for this and how can I solve this.

Thanks

I tried by changing the trigger type and it does not work.